# SQL - SUM but filter the 2 max column

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like below.

```
qid  segment task    before  after   diff
------------------------------------------
1       0    aaa       5     5       0
1       0    aaa       5     5       0
1       1    aaa       15    15      0
1       1    aaa       10    5      10
1       0    aaa       10    5       5
3       0    bbb       10    4       6
```

For each task I need to sum the before,after and diff values.But the I want to do this operation only on the High qid and segment.

For eg: for task A,

- High qid = 1
- High segment =1

This is row I want to take for task A.

For task B,

- High qid = 3
- high segment = 0

The last row is the one I want to calculate.

### Expected output:

```
task    before  after   diff
-----------------------------
aaa       25    20      10
bbb       10    4       6
```

Comment: how can after can be `25` for `aaa`?

Comment: Oh yes, its 20, modified , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `dense_rank`. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8PmjmKZQ8Rq2eS9W3nVrpQ/1).

```
with cte as
(
    select
        *,
        dense_rank() over (partition by task order by qid desc, segment desc) as rnk
    from myTable
)

select
    task,
    sum(before) as before,
    sum(after)  as after,
    sum(diff) as  diff
from cte
where rnk = 1
group by
    task
```

outoput:

```
| task | before | after | diff |
| ---- | ------ | ----- | ---- |
| aaa  | 25     | 20    | 10   |
| bbb  | 10     | 4     | 6    |
```

Comment: error near to this `(partition by task order, qid order segment desc)`

Comment: @Bhuvanesh updated my answer, and provide you the demo.

Comment: Running this query after adding one more new row is giving wrong results.

`insert into test4 values(2,1,'aaa',15,15, 0);` 

   added this row, now for task aaa the max qid 2 and for qid2 the max segment is 1, So output for the task aaa should return 

aaa,15,15,0

but it returns sum of all rows where rank=1

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation and `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (task) 
    qid, 
    segment, 
    task, 
    sum(before) before,
    sum(after) after,
    sum(diff) diff
from mytable t
group by task, qid, segment
order by task, qid desc, segment desc
```